# Is there any clear step by step tutorial of config Nginx & Unicorn on Ubuntu for Rails Web Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, unicorn

Hi,

I'm totally new to RoR development, I want to create a Rails environment with Nginx + Unicorn on Ubuntu, and deploy a Rails Web Application upon it. I've Google for the topic and read many tutorials again and again, but the steps on different article seems like vary, it really confusing me.

I've installed Nginx, Ruby, Rails on Ubuntu and tested that they're worked. I've got the 'Welcome to Nginx' page on browser, and I'd use 'rails new appname' command to created a new web application and launched it on the built-in WEBrick server, and got the default RoR welcome page of the application on browser.

But now I've no idea how to go on to config the Nginx as the reverse-proxy and Unicron as the Rails application server, to serve the web application. Does anyone ever completed such tasks with any clear step by step tutorial? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I can provide you configs for unicorn and nginx which were used on real projects. We use [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano) gem and it's 3rd version for deploying projects on the Debian/Ubuntu servers with Nginx + Unicorn. So, I will also provide you necessary parts of Capistrano configuration that relates to the unicorn.

1. Nginx config:
   https://gist.github.com/SunnyMagadan/c44e33662d27b85ea92b#file-project-name-conf
2. Unicorn config:
   https://gist.github.com/SunnyMagadan/c44e33662d27b85ea92b#file-unicorn-rb
3. Capistrano task for reloading/starting unicorn:
   https://gist.github.com/SunnyMagadan/c44e33662d27b85ea92b#file-unicorn-rake
   You can put content of this gist to /lib/capistrano/tasks/unicorn.rake file
4. Code snippet that should be added to config/deploy.rb file and it will run previous Capistrano task (restart unicorn) when deploy is finishing:

   namespace :deploy do
       after :finishing, "unicorn:restart"
   end

Comment: Hi Sunny: could you help me to clarify these points: 
I have to (1)create a my_appname.conf file on Nginx's sites-available folder, and (2)create a unicorn.rb on the root folder of my rails app, then editing them, right? (so far I haven't install Capistrano yet)

Comment: Hi, Paul. You need to add unicorn gem to your project's Gemfile: gem 'unicorn' and put unicorn.rb file to config directory. Your first notice about my_appname.conf is correct. Don't forget to edit your config files with actual path to your project's location.